# Twitter API: post on behalf of whom?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to use Twitter API so my program can post some tweets. To use it I have to register application in dev-center and get some parameters like "Consumer key", "Consumer secret" etc. Then I can use either REST API, or some libraries like twitter4j - OK, that's simple.

But the question is: who will be the "author" of such tweets? Or, in other words, where can I find them after posting? Will they be posted by application or by some user? I can't really figure out how particular user binds to registered API-application... Or how can I specify ("log-in") user to post tweet on behalf of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "author" is always going to be the authenticating user. From the [Twitter API documentation for statuses/update](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update):

> Updates the **authenticating user's** current status, also known as tweeting.

To answer your other question about authenticating with another user's username/password, it is possible but you need to get permission from Twitter. You also still need to use OAuth. Check out the [Twitter API OAuth documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a twitter account to register your application. So your account will be the author of your posts.

Comment: OK, sounds logical. But what if I want to develop app like alternative Twitter-client (desktop or mobile software), where users authenticate with their credentials and then post whatever they want. Is there any way to authenticate with login/password - not using OAuth and redirects?